# Проголосовало или проголосовали?

Tags: орфография

Как будет правильно:

> необходимо чтобы проголосовал**о** еще 2 участника.

или

> необходимо чтобы проголосовал**и** еще 2 участника.

`и` или `о`? Вот в чем вопрос!

Comment: Я бы спросил у коллег с rus.SE. Моё чувство языка говорит, что «проголосовало» правильнее, но лучше доверять мнению экспертов.

Comment: @VladD кто такие rus.SE? Я тоже склоняюсь к `о`, но зерно сомнение уже дало свои плоды :)

Comment: Ой, а мы ж тут находимся :-) Я невнимательный.

Comment: @VladD это доказывает существование скоростей выше скорости света. Только подумал, а уже тут :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если смысл в достижении нужного *количества* проголосовавших, то акцентируется числительное и предпочтительно "проголосовал**о**".

Если же подразумеваются *конкретные* участники (нужно, чтобы те двое проголосовали - тогда мы закроемся и устроим перерыв), то "проголосовал**и**" (согласование с существительным).

Comment: Это какой-то учебник или справочник может подтвердить?

Comment: Можно здесь почитать:
http://rusgram.narod.ru/2231-2256.html
§ 2245, Колебания координации в формах числа, п.2)
_Форма ед. ч. предпочитается при подлежащем - существительном не конкретно-предметного значения;
форма мн. ч. правильна тогда, когда речь идет об известном, определенном субъекте._